# Matrix inequality with convex elements

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-equations

I have the following constraint:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
t & f(x) \\ g(y) & 1
\end{bmatrix} \succ 0$$

where $f(x),g(y)$ are convex (real) positive functions of $x$ and $y$, and $t\in \mathbb{R}_+$. Is this type of constraint convex and solvable in an interface like YALMIP or CVX? Can it be transformed into an LMI?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the matrix is positive definite by writing that $A>0$? If so, I recommend $A\succ 0$

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: Generally, we consider only symmetric matrices in LMI constraints.  Your left hand side won't in general be symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that this matrix is positive definite, then this constrain is not convex unless $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are linear function.

For a 2-dimensional matrix, that it is positive definite is equivalent to:
$$ t>0,1>0,f(x)=g(y), f(x)g(y)-t<0  $$
i.e.:
$$ f(x)=g(y),  f(x)g(y)-t<0  $$
If you want these contraints to be convex, then $f(x), g(y)$ should be linear and $f(x)g(y)$ should be convex.